# Including a file from a dir

Tags: php, include

I've made a member panel all works fine, And now I want to integrate the member panel into my main site(layout).

So I will explain my dir order.
I've a `ROOT` folder where is my index.php ectra and I've made a dir called `member` I've made here my member panel which I want tostay as that to have a clean root dir. Now when I want to link. Also I've split my layout in 3 `header.php` `left-content.php` `right-content.php` you can find them in `root/include`

I'm getting this error:
`Warning: require_once(../member/core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u921594465/public_html/include/right-content.php on line 16 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../member/core/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /home/u921594465/public_html/include/right-content.php on line 16`

I used:
`require_once '../member/core/init.php';`

I use in the dir called `member` `require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_once('/home/u921594465/public_html/member/core/init.php');`

Comment: Then use https. Also It's not relevant on this context.

Comment: I get this error when i try to do `require_once ('http://www.memearch.eu/member/core/init.php');`
`http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by `